# Same-origin policy for file: URLs in Android browser?

Tags: web-browser, mobile, android, same-origin-policy

When you load a `file://` URL in an Android WebView or in the Android browser, what does it treat as the origin?  What can the Javascript on that page access?  Can it access other files in the same directory?  Other files elsewhere on the device?

Background: I know that, in desktop browsers, the same-origin policy for `file://` URLs has varied over time and from browser to browser.  For instance, some browsers used to treat all `file://` URLs as being within the same origin, so any one page could script all pages with the `file` protocol.  Today, I think some desktop browsers use the directory as the origin (e.g., `file://a/b/c.html` is in the same origin as `file://a/b/d.html` and they can script each other, but they are in a different origin from `file://a/y/z.html` and cannot script it), while I think other browsers use the entire path as the origin (i.e., `file://a/b/c.html` is in a different origin from `file://a/b/d.html` and cannot script it or any other `file` URL).  What's the situation for the Android browser / the renderer used by Android WebViews?

Comment: I'm appending the Same origin policy RFC here for everyone's future reference: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454

Comment: @Henning Klevjer that RFC does not mention the `file://` URI and it's related origin(s).

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. I think I tried to be of some sort of help that turned out not to be that valuable ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you execute a .html file using the `file://` URI  that script is run in the "file" zone. Which means that you can read files on the local file system using an XHR. (This is subject to change,  and is also easy to verify)

As with most "standards"  it depends on what browser you are using. If you are using Firefox on any system,  including android, JavaScript can only access files in its own directory and all sub directories.  But this is a [recent change FireFox's SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs) (May 1st 2012).

WebKit is a different story. If you have a script running in the `file://` zone then you can read **any file** on the local file system,  so long as the browser is running as a user with the necessary file permissions (`/etc/passwd` should always be world readable).

It should be noted that most browsers will not allow you to redirect from a web zone (http, https) to the file zone. Once upon a time you could do this,  but it was a feature that was ripe for abuse.  So if there was a DOM based XSS vulnerability in a local .html file it would be difficult exploit (I am not aware of a method of doing this, and this method would likely be a vulnerability).  Although this theoretical vulnerability maybe "cross-zone scripting"  which would allow an attacker to exfiltrate files off of the local file system,  it would be very difficult to exploit due to redirection restrictions.

Comment: Thank you!  Do Android WebViews use WebKit (i.e., use the WebKit policy for `file://` URLs that you describe)?

Comment: @D.W. They do use webkit, but I am not sure how they handle file://.  That is a very good question...  They could still be jailed.  If I had a dev environment setup I would test it using an XHR to try and GET a juicy file.

Comment: @D.W.  So what did you find out?  Did you try it?